# Make my Popup Fade in with HTML DOM CSS (JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, simple-html-dom

This is my code for the Pop-up in pure Javascript. 
When you click inside the circle, the box pops up.
I need to make an animation for the popup to fade in.
But I need to do that in pure JS and with HTML DOM Style or other JS functions.

```js
var iQueueChat   = function() {
  this.textAlign = "center";  
  this.width     = 250;
  this.height    = 444;
 
  this.createFrame();

  this.useRotate = !(/MSIE [89]\./.test(navigator.userAgent))
};
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function mouseOver(x) {
    x.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(141, 141, 141, 0.5)';
}

function mouseOut(x) {
    x.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.5)';
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

iQueueChat.prototype.chatParams = function() {
  var id       = document.getElementById("iQueueChat").attributes.getNamedItem("src").value.split('#')[1];
  var referrer = document.referrer;
  var div      = document.div;
  var title    = document.title;
  var url      = document.location.href;

  return "?id="       + encodeURIComponent(id) +
         "&referrer=" + encodeURIComponent(referrer) +
         "&title="    + encodeURIComponent(title) +
         "&urel="     + encodeURIComponent(url)
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

iQueueChat.prototype.createFrame      = function() {
    this.container                    = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
    this.container.style.display      = 'none';
    this.container.style.zIndex       = '9999999';
    this.container.style.right        = '3%';
    this.container.style.height       = this.height + 'px';
 this.container.style.boxShadow    = "1px 4px 20px 0px ";
    this.frame                        = this.container.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
    this.frame.style.backgroundColor  = 'white';
 this.frame.style.border           = '1px solid black';
    this.title                        = this.frame.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
    this.title.style.textAlign        = 'center';
 this.div                          = document.createElement('div');
 // set style of div
 this.div.style.backgroundImage    = 'url("'+ this.icon1 +'")';
 this.div.style.width              = '56px';
 this.div.style.height             = '56px';
 this.div.style.backgroundSize     = '35px 35px';
    this.div.style.backgroundRepeat   = 'no-repeat';
    this.div.style.backgroundPosition = 'center center';
 this.div.style.zIndex             = '9999999';
 this.div.style.display            = 'block';
 this.div.style.position           = 'fixed';
 this.div.style.bottom             = '3%';
 this.div.style.right              = '3%';
 this.div.style.backgroundColor    = 'rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.7)';
 this.div.style.backgroundImage    = 'url("'+ this.icon1 +'")';
 this.div.style.borderWidth        = '1px';
 this.div.style.borderStyle        = 'solid';
 this.div.style.cursor             = 'pointer';
    this.div.style.textAlign          = 'center';
    this.div.style.borderRadius       = "50%";
 this.div.style.borderColor        = 'gray';
 this.div.onmouseover              = function() {mouseOver(this)};
 this.div.onmouseout               = function() {mouseOut(this)};
 this.div.setAttribute("id", "Div1");
 document.body.appendChild(this.div);
 this.div.iQueueChat = this;

 EventHandler.bind(this.div, 'click', function(event) {
  EventHandler.stopHere(event);
  this.iQueueChat.toggle();
  })
  
  this.iframe                    = document.createElement('iframe')
  this.iframe.frameBorder        = 0;
  this.iframe.style.display      = 'none';
  this.iframe.style.width        = '100%';
  this.iframe.style.scrolling    = 'no';
  this.iframe.style.borderRadius = '8px';
  this.iframe.style.opacity      = 1;
  this.iframe.style.height       = this.height + 'px';
  if (isMobile.any) {
    this.iframe.setAttribute('src', this.url + '&mobile=no');
  } else {
    this.iframe.setAttribute('src', this.url);
  }
  this.frame.appendChild(this.iframe);
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


iQueueChat.prototype.initialize = function(data) {
  this.id               = document.getElementById("iQueueChat").attributes.getNamedItem("src").value.split('#')[1];
  this.title.innerHTML  = '';
  var icon              = document.createElement('img');
  if (data.status == 'online') {
    icon.src = 'https://chat.intratel.nl' + this.id.replace('{','/').replace('}','/') + 'onlineicon.png';
  } else {
    icon.src = 'https://chat.intratel.nl' + this.id.replace('{','/').replace('}','/') + 'offlineicon.png';
  }
  icon.setAttribute('align', 'center');
  icon.setAttribute('hspace', 8);
  icon.width                          = 20;
  this.title.style.display            = 'none';
  this.div.style.backgroundRepeat     = 'no-repeat';
  this.div.style.backgroundPosition   = 'center center';
  this.div.style.backgroundImage      = 'url("'+ this.icon1 +'")';
  this.div.style.backgroundSize       = '35px';
  this.div.style.backgroundRepeat     = 'no-repeat';
  this.div.style.backgroundPosition   = 'center center';
  this.frame.style.color              = data.color.text;
  this.frame.style.borderWidth        = '1px';
  this.frame.style.borderStyle        = 'solid';
  this.frame.style.borderColor        = 'black';
  this.container.style.position       = 'fixed';
  this.position                       = data.position;
  this.applyPosition();

}

iQueueChat.prototype.applyPosition = function() {
  if (!this.position) {
    this.position = {
      vertical: 'right',
      horizontal: 'bottom'
    };

    this.container.style.position = 'fixed';
  }
  this.frame.style.width     = this.width + 'px';
  this.frame.style.height    = this.height + 'px';
  this.frame.style.top       = '0px';
  this.iframe.style.position = 'relative';
  this.iframe.style.top      = '0px';

  if (this.useRotate) {
    this.positionRotate()
  } else {
    this.positionLegacy();
  }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

iQueueChat.prototype.applyBorderRadius = function(position, enabled) {
  var radiuse      = enabled ? '50%' : '50%';
  var radiusFrame  = enabled ? '10px' : '10px';
  
  this.div.style['webkitBorder' + position + 'Radius'] = radiuse;
  this.div.style['mozBorder'    + position + 'Radius'] = radiuse;
  this.div.style['oBorder'      + position + 'Radius'] = radiuse;
  this.div.style['border'       + position + 'Radius'] = radiuse;

  this.frame.style['webkitBorder' + position + 'Radius'] = radiusFrame;
  this.frame.style['mozBorder'    + position + 'Radius'] = radiusFrame;
  this.frame.style['oBorder'      + position + 'Radius'] = radiusFrame;
  this.frame.style['border'       + position + 'Radius'] = radiusFrame;
  
  this.container.style['webkitBorder' + position + 'Radius'] = radiusFrame;
  this.container.style['mozBorder'    + position + 'Radius'] = radiusFrame;
  this.container.style['oBorder'      + position + 'Radius'] = radiusFrame;
  this.container.style['border'       + position + 'Radius'] = radiusFrame;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

iQueueChat.prototype.positionLegacy = function() {
  
  this.title.style.writingMode = 'inherit';
  switch (this.position.horizontal) {
    case 'center': this.container.style.bottom = '13%';
                   this.container.style.height = '1px';
                   this.frame.style.position   = 'relative';
                   this.frame.style.top = (0 - this.height / 2) + 'px';
       this.applyBorderRadius('TopLeft', true);       //  Border rond of niet
       this.applyBorderRadius('TopRight', true);      //  Border rond of niet
       this.applyBorderRadius('BottomLeft', true);    //  Border rond of niet
       this.applyBorderRadius('BottomRight', true);   //  Border rond of niet
                   if (this.isOpen()) {
                     this.frame.style.height = (this.height - 2) + 'px';

                     this.iframe.style.top = (0 - this.height) + 'px';
                   } else {
                     if (this.position.vertical == 'left') {
                       this.frame.style.width = this.width + 'px';
                     } else {
                       this.frame.style.width = '0px';
                     }
                   }
                   break;

    case 'bottom': this.container.style.bottom = '13%';
                   this.frame.style.position   = 'static';
                   this.frame.style.top        = '0px';
       this.applyBorderRadius('TopLeft', true);      //  Border rond of niet
       this.applyBorderRadius('TopRight', true);     //  Border rond of niet
       this.applyBorderRadius('BottomLeft', true);   //  Border rond of niet
       this.applyBorderRadius('BottomRight', true);  //  Border rond of niet
                   if (!this.isOpen()) {
                    this.frame.style.height = this.title.offsetHeight + 'px';
                   }
                   break;
  }
}

iQueueChat.prototype.positionRotate = function() {

  switch (this.position.horizontal) {
 
    case 'bottom': this.container.style.bottom    = '13%';  // margin - bottom
       this.container.style.boxShadow = "1px 4px 20px 0px ";
                   this.frame.style.position      = 'static';
                   this.frame.style.top           = '0px';
       this.applyBorderRadius('TopLeft', true);      //  Border rond of niet
       this.applyBorderRadius('TopRight', true);     //  Border rond of niet
       this.applyBorderRadius('BottomLeft', true);   //  Border rond of niet
       this.applyBorderRadius('BottomRight', true);  //  Border rond of niet
                   this.container.style.height  = (this.height + this.title.offsetHeight) + 'px';
                   this.frame.style.height      = (this.height + this.title.offsetHeight) + 'px';
                   if (!this.isOpen()) {
                    this.container.style.height = this.title.offsetHeight + 'px';
                    this.frame.style.height     = this.title.offsetHeight + 'px';
                    this.frame.style.top        = '0px';
        this.applyBorderRadius('TopLeft', true);      //  Border rond of niet
     this.applyBorderRadius('TopRight', true);     //  Border rond of niet
     this.applyBorderRadius('BottomLeft', true);   //  Border rond of niet
     this.applyBorderRadius('BottomRight', true);  //  Border rond of niet
                   }
                   break;
  }
  switch (this.position.vertical) {
    case 'left':  
                  this.container.style.right = '3%';
      if (!this.isOpen()) {
     this.container.style.right = '3%';  
      }

    case 'right': 
                  this.container.style.right = '3%';
      if (!this.isOpen()) {
     this.container.style.right = '3%';  
      }
                  break; 
  }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

iQueueChat.prototype.isOpen = function() {
  return this.iframe.style.display == 'block';
  
}

iQueueChat.prototype.open = function() {
  if (isMobile.any) {
    window.open(this.url + '&mobile=yes');
  } else {
    this.iframe.style.display         = 'block';
 this.container.style.display      = 'block';
 this.div.style.backgroundImage    = 'url("'+ this.icon2 +'")';
    this.div.style.backgroundSize     = '20px 20px';
    this.div.style.backgroundRepeat   = 'no-repeat';
    this.div.style.backgroundPosition = 'center center';
    this.applyPosition();
  }
}

iQueueChat.prototype.close = function() {
  this.iframe.style.display          = 'none';
  this.container.style.display       = 'none';
  this.div.style.backgroundImage     = 'url("'+ this.icon1 +'")';
  this.div.style.backgroundSize      = '35px 35px';
  this.div.style.backgroundRepeat    = 'no-repeat';
  this.div.style.backgroundPosition  = 'center center';
  
  this.applyPosition();
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

iQueueChat.prototype.toggle = function() {
  if (this.isOpen()) {
    this.close();
  } else {
   
    this.open();
  }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function initializeiQueueChat() {
  window.iQueueChat = new iQueueChat();
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var EventHandler = {
  bind: function(el, ev, fn){
    if (window.addEventListener) {
      el.addEventListener(ev, fn, false);
    } else if(window.attachEvent) {
      el.attachEvent('on' + ev, fn);
    } else {
      el['on' + ev] = fn;
    }
  },
  stopHere: function(event) {
    var event = event ? event : window.event;
    if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
    if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();
    if (event.cancelBubble!=null) event.cancelBubble = true;
  }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

EventHandler.bind(window, 'load', initializeiQueueChat)
EventHandler.bind(document, 'page:load', initializeiQueueChat)

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

EventHandler.bind(window, 'message', function(event) {
  window.iQueueChat.processMessage(JSON.parse(event.data));
});

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



 
!function(a){var b=/iPhone/i,c=/iPod/i,d=/iPad/i,e=/(?=.*\bAndroid\b)(?=.*\bMobile\b)/i,f=/Android/i,g=/(?=.*\bAndroid\b)(?=.*\bSD4930UR\b)/i,h=/(?=.*\bAndroid\b)(?=.*\b(?:KFOT|KFTT|KFJWI|KFJWA|KFSOWI|KFTHWI|KFTHWA|KFAPWI|KFAPWA|KFARWI|KFASWI|KFSAWI|KFSAWA)\b)/i,i=/IEMobile/i,j=/(?=.*\bWindows\b)(?=.*\bARM\b)/i,k=/BlackBerry/i,l=/BB10/i,m=/Opera Mini/i,n=/(CriOS|Chrome)(?=.*\bMobile\b)/i,o=/(?=.*\bFirefox\b)(?=.*\bMobile\b)/i,p=new RegExp("(?:Nexus 7|BNTV250|Kindle Fire|Silk|GT-P1000)","i"),q=function(a,b){return a.test(b)},r=function(a){var r=a||navigator.userAgent,s=r.split("[FBAN");return"undefined"!=typeof s[1]&&(r=s[0]),this.apple={phone:q(b,r),ipod:q(c,r),tablet:!q(b,r)&&q(d,r),device:q(b,r)||q(c,r)||q(d,r)},this.amazon={phone:q(g,r),tablet:!q(g,r)&&q(h,r),device:q(g,r)||q(h,r)},this.android={phone:q(g,r)||q(e,r),tablet:!q(g,r)&&!q(e,r)&&(q(h,r)||q(f,r)),device:q(g,r)||q(h,r)||q(e,r)||q(f,r)},this.windows={phone:q(i,r),tablet:q(j,r),device:q(i,r)||q(j,r)},this.other={blackberry:q(k,r),blackberry10:q(l,r),opera:q(m,r),firefox:q(o,r),chrome:q(n,r),device:q(k,r)||q(l,r)||q(m,r)||q(o,r)||q(n,r)},this.seven_inch=q(p,r),this.any=this.apple.device||this.android.device||this.windows.device||this.other.device||this.seven_inch,this.phone=this.apple.phone||this.android.phone||this.windows.phone,this.tablet=this.apple.tablet||this.android.tablet||this.windows.tablet,"undefined"==typeof window?this:void 0},s=function(){var a=new r;return a.Class=r,a};"undefined"!=typeof module&&module.exports&&"undefined"==typeof window?module.exports=r:"undefined"!=typeof module&&module.exports&&"undefined"!=typeof window?module.exports=s():"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define("isMobile",[],a.isMobile=s()):a.isMobile=s()}(this);
```

Could anyone make my popup fade in when you click on the circle?
Instead of just displaying, I like to fade in the popup.
Pleasse help me!
Many thanks!
Please use my code snippet and edit it.

Comment: You must share your HTML code as well.

Comment: The HTML is generated in HTML Dom JS, so this is my html code

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a javascript library like [jQuery](https://jquery.com/download/) for your animation. 
To add jQuery to your page add this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>` between your `<style>` and `<script>` as per screenshot:[image]

You can just add it to your page (if not already added) and then modify like so:

```
iQueueChat.prototype.toggle = function() {
  if (this.isOpen()) {
    $(this).hide(1200); // You can play around with fadeOut, slideUp. 1200 is the speed of the animation
  } else {

    $(this).show(1200); // You can play around with fadeIn, slideDown. 1200 is the speed of the animation
  }
}
```

Comment: The html is generated in pure JS and HTML DOM, so how do I include the Jquery library?

Comment: Try to modify my code to make it work!, this JS is 1 JS file, all html is generated inside the HTML DOM JS file, i dont have any other code.